# How to add metadata to my SPL token

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, metadata, spl-token-program

I'm trying to add metadata to my token on the Devnet and every solution listed on the documentation doesn't seem to work.

I tried to:

- update it from here: https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/update but it gives me this error:

[image]

- update it from here: https://app.strataprotocol.com/edit-metadata?cluster=devnet but it throws this error

[image]

- update it using this guide https://github.com/jacobcreech/Token-Creator but the `CreateMetadataV2` function doesn't exist in the `@metaplex-foundation/js` library

Also, note that I didn't remove the mint authority and I'm using the wallet that created the token when I'm trying to update the metadata.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I honestly don't know what.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using the `Token-Creator` guide, it looks like the type for `CreateMetadataV2` changed to `CreateMetadataAccountV2`, which you can create using: https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/metaplex-program-library/docs/token-metadata/index.html#createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction